# trouble with getting value from mysql to php

Tags: php, html, mysql

i want to retrieve value from mysql to php here is code 
i want to retrieve value from mysql to php here is code

```
   <?php
    include 'config.php'; 
$query = "SELECT * FROM dealerpostproperty  dp
LEFT JOIN property_type ON property_type.id = dp.property_Id LEFT JOIN registration ON registration.UserName = dp.UserName
WHERE dp.City = 'Navi Mumbai'
";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die ("Query failed");
//get the number of rows in our result so we can use it in a for loop
$numrows = (mysql_num_rows ($result));
// loop to create rows
if($numrows >= 1){
for ($r = 0; $r <= $numrows; $r++) {
// loop to create columns
while ($friendList = mysql_fetch_array($result))
 {     
 $_SESSION['PropertyId'] = $friendList['property_Id'];

//Create table

echo " <tr> <td class='td2'>";

echo '<a href=# alt=Image Tooltip rel=tooltip content="<div class=td2><div id=imagcon><img src=img/1.jpg class=tooltip-image/></div><div id=con>'.$friendList['BedRooms'].' bhk </div><div id=con>'.$friendList['property_type'].'</div><div id=con>Area:'.$friendList['CoveredArea'].'</div><div id=con> '.$friendList['Type_cust'].' :'.$friendList['FirstName'].' '.$friendList['LastName'].' </div> <div id=con> <a href=# > View All Details </a>   </div>
<br/>
  <div id=con> <a href=# >';

 echo " <img src='Dealer/images/email.png' style='width:15px;height:15px' />";  

 echo ' Contact Advertiser </a>  </div> </div>
 ">'.$friendList['Name_of_ProjOrSociety'].'</a>'.'<br>';

echo "
</td>
<td ></td>

</tr>

<tr>
<td>".$friendList['City']."  


</td>
<td>


</td>

</tr> ";
echo $friendList['dp.City'];
echo "fffff";

 }}
}

?>
```

i want to retrive value from

```
<td>".$friendList['City']."  


</td>
```

i tried this but not working what to do ????? i am new in php

???????????????????????????????????????

```
<td>".$friendList['dp.City']."  


    </td>
```

Comment: Please complete your while loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can u please complete your while loop.
when u are using mysql_fetch_array ,the values are stored as indexed array not as associative array. i am assuming city is stored in the 0th index of the array.please check with your query result what is the position of the city.

```
while ($friendList = mysql_fetch_array($result))
```

{

```
$city=$friendlist[0];
```

}

Comment: there is nothing to do with while loop..i just want city value i have used joins

Comment: $result = mysql_query("SELECT id, name FROM mytable");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
    printf("ID: %s  Name: %s", $row[0], $row[1]);  
}

Comment: when u are using mysql_fetch_array ,the values are stored as indexed array not as associative array.

Comment: i am getting other values properly.. only having trouble with city.because there is ambigious column in joins..so how can i differ them in php

Comment: bro u need to use alias for the city in your query because while fetching if u have two columns with the same name than ambiguity will arise.

Comment: can u pls give me the structure of the tables so that i can check ur query.

Comment: rishabh i used all column names with alias insted of star * its working now.thanks

Comment: @deepak can u pls mark my answer as answered

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
while($friendList = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
   echo $friendList['City'];
}
```

Comment: there is alias i have given to city but when i am trying to retrive with that alias its throwing error

Comment: @deepak Is the value of the alias a column in your database?  Then change $friendList['aliasCity'];

Answer (score 0):

Hope this works fine

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id, name FROM mytable"); 
$friendList = mysql_fetch_array($result)
while ($result as $row )) {
      $row['city'];
 }
```

and dont use my_sql* use PDO